# Oracle query Round up or down to nearest 15 minute interval

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
08-SEP-20 08:55:05
08-SEP-20 15:36:13
```

The query below is working correctly for 15:36:13 in that it rounds to 15:30 but the 8:55:05 is rounding down to 08:45 when it should be rounding to 09:00

```
select event_date,trunc(event_date,'mi') - numtodsinterval(  mod(to_char(event_date,'mi'),15),  'minute'  ) as nearest_quarter
from time_source_in_all where empno = '002307718' and event_date between  '8-sep-2020' and '9-sep-2020'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select trunc(event_date, 'HH') + round(extract(minute from event_date) / 15) * interval '15' minute )
. . .
```

Note:  I prefer the `extract()` because it is standard SQL.  But it assumes that the column is a `timestamp` and not a `date`.

or the equivalent:

```
select trunc(event_date, 'HH') + numtodsinterval(round(to_number(to_char(event_date, 'MI')) / 15) * 15, 'minute')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is a date field

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT event_date,
       TRUNC( event_date, 'HH' )
         + ROUND( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM CAST( event_date AS TIMESTAMP ) ) / 15 )
           * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
         AS rounded_15_event_date
FROM   table_name
```

or:

```sql
SELECT event_date,
       TRUNC( event_date, 'HH' )
         + ROUND( ( event_date - TRUNC( event_date, 'HH' ) ) * 24 * 4 )
           * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
         AS rounded_15_event_date
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( event_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-09-08' + INTERVAL '08:55:05' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-09-08' + INTERVAL '15:36:13' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> ```
> EVENT_DATE          | ROUNDED_15_EVENT_DATE
> :------------------ | :--------------------
> 2020-09-08 08:55:05 | 2020-09-08 09:00:00  
> 2020-09-08 15:36:13 | 2020-09-08 15:30:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=602813beab4b564820a44142edcb37d7)*